# How to write user defined compare for std::sort()

Tags: c++, sorting, compare

I have a two dimensional vector array `vector<vector<int> >` and I need to sort the vectors inside it in order. So... I thought I would write a function which compare two vectors and then use `sort()`

However I couldn't understand and then was not able to find anywhere the proper syntax for this. Here is my compare function:

```
bool vectorcompare (vector<int> v, vector<int> w){ 
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
        if(v[i]<w[i]) return 1;
        if(v[i]>w[i]) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

And then I call sort function, which doesn't work:

```
sort(vector.begin(),vector.end(), vectorcompare());
```

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I see that the question is misguided, but why is it getting downvoted so badly? It's a beginner question, yes, but it is not effortlessly asking for a ready-made solution.

Comment: You may not need to write your own comparison function. `std::vector` already has an `operator<` defined that performs the equivalent of `std::lexicographical_compare`. Have you tried simply calling `std::sort` on your vector<vector> ?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that. I will most certainly try to do it this way.

Comment: Yes. It works just without any extra function. How do I find out things like this? operator< for std::vector is not mentioned in [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) for example.

Comment: That site is regularly criticized on SO for being incomplete and having poor information. [This site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site may be better. Of course, the best reference is the [ISO Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/).

Comment: I don't know about two years ago, but now it is actually listed at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/ under "Non-member function overloads" - "Relational operators".

Answer (score 12):

#### First, your compile error:

```
sort(vector.begin(),vector.end(), vectorcompare());
```

`vectorcompare` is a function, not a *type*. That is, it's not an object that you can construct. So you don't do `()` on it; you just pass the function as is:

```
sort(vector.begin(),vector.end(), vectorcompare);
```

#### Now, for a worse problem:

```
bool vectorcompare (vector<int> v, vector<int> w)
```

Take your parameters by `const&`, not by value. `std::vector`s are big; you shouldn't needlessly copy them.

#### And an even worse problem:

```
for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
    if(v[i]<w[i]) return 1;
    if(v[i]>w[i]) return 0;
}
return 1;
```

This does not constitute a [strict-weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering). This provides less than *or equals to*, which is not a strict-weak ordering. `std::sort` requires sorting based on a strict-weak ordering.

Comment: Oh... ok. I will go and think about it, thank you! At least it compiles without errors now

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to write your own comparison function. `std::vector` already has an `operator<` defined that performs the equivalent of `std::lexicographical_compare`. Have you tried simply calling `std::sort` on your `vector<vector>`?

Note: added my comment as this answer because the user found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this site, it has a nice example](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

In your case, you would call `std::sort` like this:

```
sort(vector.begin(),vector.end(), vectorcompare);
```

Comment: Yes, I looked there before. So, it looks like my function should work. There are many discussions on this website with examples like `bool compare(const vector<int> &v, const vector<int> &w)` I didn't understand why, and wasn't sure if I did it right.